# Button Above linearlayout Android XML UI

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have this problem...

This is a screenshot of my XML File in Android Studio[image]

this is the code...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/gris_300"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_oval"
        android:text="AGREGAR ITEMS"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="false"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_ver_pedido"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/carrito" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu3"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_ver_estado"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_estado" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_llamar"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView26"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_llamar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu7"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_ver_mesa"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_ver_mesa" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pedido" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ver mi ticket"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_pagar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView24"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu6"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView43"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView46"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mis rewards"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_uber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Llamar a un taxi/uber"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView44"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView54"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Regalar una gift card"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is a screnshot of my device...

[image]

I tried Framelayout...relative...

Help!

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting the button below the layout within the xml. Keep everything the same.  The layout is ordering the views.  So if the button is first, the next layout with go above it. So in your case, you would want the button to be called second so it gets put above your second layout. If you have trouble I can post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Final code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/gris_300"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="false"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_ver_pedido"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/carrito" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView19"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu3"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_ver_estado"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_estado" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_llamar"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView26"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_llamar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu7"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_ver_mesa"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_ver_mesa" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView18"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pedido" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ver mi ticket"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_pagar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView24"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/text_menu6"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView43"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView46"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mis rewards"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_uber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Llamar a un taxi/uber"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView44"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pagar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView54"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Regalar una gift card"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_oval"
        android:text="AGREGAR ITEMS"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: so the idea is to use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout!